# How to make a header-only library with cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries

How to make a project in cmake that collects all c++ files into one header?

I have this project structure.

```
/
  project/
     folder1/
         file.cpp
         file.hpp
     folder2/
         ...etc
     CMakeLists.txt
  tests/
     test.cpp
     CMakeLists.txt
CMakeList.txt
```

root cmakelists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

project ("CMakeProject"
    LANGUAGES C CXX)

set(CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX ".exe")

include(GNUInstallDirs)

add_subdirectory ("project")


option(ENABLE_TESTING OFF)

if (ENABLE_TESTING)
    enable_testing()
    add_subdirectory("tests")
endif()
```

CMakeLists.txt in project

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

file(GLOB projectSRC
    "*/*.cpp"
    "*/*.hpp"
    "*.cpp"
    "*.hpp"
)

add_library(project INTERFACE)

message(STATUS "CMake inatall directory: " ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR})
target_include_directories(project 
    INTERFACE 
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROJECT_INCLUDE_DIR}>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}>)
```

and test cmakelist.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

# install Catch2 testing library
# (https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/master/docs/cmake-integration.md#installing-catch2-from-git-repository or use packet manager)
find_package(Catch2 REQUIRED)

file(GLOB testSRC
    "*.cpp"
)

add_executable(tests ${testSRC})

target_link_libraries(tests
    Catch2::Catch2
    project)

include(CTest)
include(Catch)
catch_discover_tests(tests)
```

How to generate one header and use it (in tests or other projects) or make this library able to have templates? The first is better.

Comment: If you want everything in headers, why are you putting things into .cpp files in the first place??

Comment: This might not be possible.  You can define variables that are local to single cpp file and if you've done that then there is a potential you'll be redefining something if multiple cpp file define the same variable.

Comment: If it is important I can move everything in headers but not into one.

Comment: I never personally tried doing this. However, you can check open source projects on github that do this. You might get good pointers from playing with their projects. I know of 2, there is pybind11 and catch2 that are header only libraries.

Comment: A good reference with line by line explanation can be found here: https://dominikberner.ch/cmake-interface-lib/

Answer (score 61, accepted):

> How to make a header-only library with cmake?

Like this:

```
add_library(project INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(project INTERFACE .)
```

Then in the target that uses the library:

```
target_link_libraries(dependee
    PUBLIC/INTERFACE/PRIVATE # pick one
    project)
```

and include the header like this:

```
#include <project/folder1/file.hpp>
```

Comment: I found that in the target_link_libraries if the header only library is INTERFACE then when building the project cmake will not detect the header files of the library.

Comment: Strictly speaking, shouldn't the scope of '.' in target_include_directories be PUBLIC, vs. INTERFACE? Technically the files in that directory include other files in that directory. I understand that, practically speaking, it makes no difference, since you will never actually build this project.  I suppose it would allow you to make one less change if you ever add an implementation file and change the library to PUBLIC (non-header-only).

Comment: @ToddR If the library is an "INTERFACE", that keyword can only be "INTERFACE".

Comment: Worth noting: Since CMake 3.19 interface libraries can be created with source files, i.e. `add_library(project INTERFACE file1.hpp file2.hpp)`. If you are working with Visual Studio, those headers will now show up under the generated project.

Comment: I can confirm, @sebrockm's suggested approach works, is most idiomatic and also necessary to properly get CMake to register the dependency between a target and a generated header file...

Comment: I tried this with gcc and clang, had to use `#include <folder1/file.h>`